# Trying to connect internet from my laptop to my desktop, but there's no share tab

Tags: windows-7, internet-connection, connection-sharing

I'm using Windows 7 on both my laptop (Starter) and desktop (Ultimate), and I am trying to connect to the internet from my desktop through my laptop. I have followed instructions from articles concerning this, and the only issue is that I have no Sharing tab in the Properties window for my connection. Without the Sharing tab, I cannot check the box that will allow me to share internet.

Any help?

Comment: Is the Laptop using a wireless connection for this configuration?  Does the desktop have a wireless card in it?

Answer (score 1):

I think one of your issues is a problem with your wireless card's drivers. Some drivers support connection sharing while others don't. [This Microsoft forum thread](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/w7itpronetworking/thread/5d188cfb-f5ca-4e18-ba48-36b76c82e5f0) basically says as much.

I think you may be able to accomplish what you want by using an *ad hoc* wireless network setup on your laptop which the desktop would then be able to connect to, wirelessly.

Another source of issues for you may be with Windows 7 Starter. I don't believe it provides Internet Connection Sharing out of the box. See [this Gizmodo article](http://gizmodo.com/5421088/get-internet-connection-sharing-in-windows-7-starter-in-one-easy-step) for details and how to work around the issue.

Answer (score 0):

> [Internet + Access point WiFi]--------{1}------[laptop]========={2}======[desktop]
>
> {1}: wireless connection
>   {2}: wire connection

You just need Sharing Tab on your laptop.

You go to **Network Connections**, enable at least **02** connections. In your case, one is Wireless connection, other one is Wire connection, then you will see Sharing Tab again.

Read more detail [here...](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/Using-ICS-Internet-Connection-Sharing)